# Parse OFX (Open Financial Exchange document) using Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, ofx

I searched for quite some time to find examples of Coldfusion parsing OFX files but can't find anything. Can anyone please assist with some sample code or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I couldn’t find how OFX files are formatted with some quick searches, but Wikipedia referenced XML. Have you tried XMLParse()? If you can’t find a library to read the file, you might have to parse it yourself.

Comment: ... Might also be SGML. Have you looked into using a java library? May be an exising lib you could use that would save you from reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Might try the opensource OFX4J java lib.

Answer (score -1):

I have built a library that parses out ZIP XML files like `.docx`. You might want to try it out.

First see if you can unzip and read the files

```
string function extractDocx(required string pathToDocX) {

  cfzip(action="read", file=arguments.pathToDocx, entrypath="word\document.xml", variable="this.xmlString");

  this.xmlPara = xmlparse(this.xmlString).document.body;


  return ReadNode(this.xmlPara);
  }
```

The result then needs to go to a recursive parser. See:

https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/11/extracting-text-html-out-word-docx-files/
https://github.com/jmohler1970/WordExtractor_demo
https://github.com/jmohler1970/WordExtractor